# Yii2 установить пустое значение

Tags: php, yii2

Есть таблица deal, которая состоит из id, name, connect_deal. Последний столбец содержит id связанной строки этой же таблицы, если он есть. Чтобы удалить значения из connect_deal выполняю следующий код:

```
    $deal = Deal::findOne($id);
    $conId = $deal->connectDeal;
    $deal->connectDeal = null;
    if ($deal->save()) {
        $upDeal = Deal::findOne($conId);
        $upDeal->connectDeal = null;
        $result = $upDeal->save();
        if ($result) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Связь успешно удалена');
            return $this->refresh();
        }
    }
    ....
```

В итоге данные удаляются, как мне и нужно, но получается ошибка, дебагер выделяет строку `$upDeal->connectDeal = null;` и выводит warning `Creating default object from empty value`, при том, что `$deal->connectDeal = null` вопросов у программы не вызывает. С чем может быть связана ошибка и как её решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что Вы пытаетесь присвоить свойство `connectDeal` несуществующему объекту. Иными словами `$upDeal = Deal::findOne($conId);` в определенных ситуациях выдает null. Например, когда связи не было изначально, или связная запись в таблице не существует

Добавьте проверку на 2ой поиск `Deal::findOne($conId)`

```
    $deal = Deal::findOne($id);
    $conId = $deal->connectDeal;
    $deal->connectDeal = null;
    if ($deal->save() && ($upDeal = Deal::findOne($conId)) !== null) {

        $upDeal->connectDeal = null;
        $result = $upDeal->save();
        if ($result) {
           Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Связь успешно удалена');
           return $this->refresh();
        }

    }
```